# Azure devops self-host deploy agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

If I am using a self-hosted deployment agent for my azure devops Ci\CD pipeline , and the pipeline is regarding to deploy Azure databricks notebook and also to build Azure sql database project and deploy dacpac ,

what component is required to be installed in that self-host agent ?

Comment: All of this is quite nicely documented at [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops). In its current form, this question is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask].

Comment: I don't understand , where does it mention anything?

Comment: The entire document is filled with relevant information, like the prerequisites for such a machine. If you have a more explicit question, please make clear what that question is. In short: to deploy something (_anything_) to Azure, you can use tools like Azure CLI, PowerShell, ARM et cetera. You can build pipelines to leverage these tools without requirements for the agent.

Answer (score 0):

> what component is required to be installed in that self-host agent ?

Prerequisites:

•   Windows 7, 8.1, or 10 (if using a client OS)

•   Windows 2008 R2 SP1 or higher (if using a server OS)

•   PowerShell 3.0 or higher

•   .NET Framework 4.6.2 or higher

> Note - the minimum required .NET version for build agents is 4.6.2 or
> higher. If you're building from a Subversion repo, you must install
> the Subversion client on the machine.

You should run agent setup manually the first time.

Prepare permissions

Information security for self-hosted agents

Authenticate with a personal access token (PAT)

Confirm the user has permission

[Download and configure the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent)

> Before you install a self-hosted agent you might want to see if a
> Microsoft-hosted agent pool will work for you. In many cases this is
> the simplest way to get going.

For more information refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install